# SQL Server: Aligning Pivot Table Rows

Tags: sql-server, pivot, common-table-expression

I have two tables that's defined by the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Portfolio.DailyStats
(Date date NOT NULL,
NAV int NOT NULL,
SP500 decimal(8,4) NULL,
R2K decimal(8,4) NULL,
NetExp decimal(8,4) NULL,
GrossExp decimal(8,4) NULL,)
GO

CREATE TABLE Portfolio.DailyPortfolio
(BbgID varchar(30) NOT NULL,
Ticker varchar(22) NULL,
Cusip char(9) NULL,
SecurityDescription varchar(50) NOT NULL,
AssetCategory varchar(25) NOT NULL,
LSPosition char(3) NULL,
Ccy varchar(25) NOT NULL,
Quantity int NULL,
AvgCost decimal(7,3) NULL,
PriceLocal decimal(7,3) NULL,
Cost int NULL,
MktValNet int NULL,
GLPeriod int NULL,
Beta decimal(4,2) NULL,
BetaExpNet int NULL,
BetaExpGross int NULL,
Delta decimal(4,2) NULL,
DeltaExpNet int NULL,
DeltaExpGross int NULL,
Issuer varchar(48) NOT NULL,
Country varchar(30) NOT NULL,
Region varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Sector varchar(30) NOT NULL,
Industry varchar(48) NOT NULL,
MktCapCategory varchar(24) NULL,
MktCapEnd int NULL,
Date date NOT NULL,
PortfolioID  AS BbgID+LSPosition+ Convert(varchar(8),Date,112) Persisted 
Primary Key)
GO
```

I am trying to create where I can look at the PNL Contribution for each issuer by Year where each year is represented by a column. PNL Contribution is defined as the SUM(GLPeriod) for each year / AVG(NAV) for that year. As an example, my final output should look like this:

```
Issuer| 2015|   2016|   2017|
:-----|-----|-------|-------|
Issuer A|   -0.012550646|   -0.012339104|   NULL|
Issuer B|   -0.00701487|    -0.000759621|   -0.004905285|
Issuer C|   NULL|   -0.002270388|   -0.003730801|
```

Instead by current output looks like this:

```
Issuer| 2015|   2016|   2017|
:-----|-----|-------|-------|
Issuer A|   NULL|   -0.012339104|   NULL|
Issuer A|   -0.012550646|   NULL|   NULL|
Issuer B|   NULL|   NULL|   -0.004905285|
Issuer B|   NULL|   -0.000759621|   NULL|
Issuer B|   -0.00701487|    NULL|   NULL|
Issuer C|   NULL|   NULL|   -0.003730801|
Issuer C|   NULL|   -0.002270388|   NULL|
```

Here the code I used:

```
CREATE VIEW Portfolio.ContributionByYear
AS
WITH a
AS
(
SELECT Issuer, SUM(GLPeriod) PNL, DATEPART(yyyy, Date) Year
FROM Portfolio.DailyPortfolio
GROUP BY Issuer, DATEPART(yyyy, Date)
)
,
b AS
(
SELECT AVG(CAST(NAV AS BIGINT)) AvgNAV, DATEPART(yyyy, Date) Year
FROM Portfolio.DailyStats
GROUP BY DATEPART(yyyy, Date)
),
c AS
(
SELECT a.Issuer, a.PNL, a.Year, b.AvgNAV , CONVERT( decimal (15,3), 
a.PNL)/CONVERT( decimal (15,3), b.AvgNAV) [Contrib]
FROM a
JOIN b
ON a.Year = b.Year
)
SELECT Issuer, [2015],[2016],[2017]
FROM c
PIVOT
(
SUM(c.Contrib)
FOR [Year] IN ([2015],[2016],[2017])
) AS PivotTable
GO
```

The other problem I have with this code is that I am using a SUM aggregate function in PivotTable but it's actually not adding anything. It's just flipping the data from rows to column. However I can't seem to pivot the data without using some kind of aggregate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing  `a.PNL` and `b.AvgNAV` from the `c` CTE..

```
SELECT a.Issuer, a.Year, --here `a.PNL` and `b.AvgNAV` is removed 
       CONVERT( decimal (15,3), a.PNL)/CONVERT( decimal (15,3), b.AvgNAV) [Contrib]
FROM a
JOIN b
ON a.Year = b.Year
```

Start giving proper names to `Cte's`, it makes the code more readable

```
CREATE VIEW Portfolio.ContributionByYear
AS
WITH cteDailyPortfolio
AS
(
SELECT Issuer, SUM(GLPeriod) PNL, DATEPART(yyyy, Date) Year
FROM Portfolio.DailyPortfolio
GROUP BY Issuer, DATEPART(yyyy, Date)
),
cteDailyStats AS
(
SELECT AVG(CAST(NAV AS BIGINT)) AvgNAV, DATEPART(yyyy, Date) Year
FROM Portfolio.DailyStats
GROUP BY DATEPART(yyyy, Date)
),
pivotData AS
(
SELECT a.Issuer, a.Year, --here `a.PNL` and `b.AvgNAV` is removed 
      CONVERT( decimal (15,3), a.PNL)/CONVERT( decimal (15,3), b.AvgNAV) [Contrib]
FROM cteDailyPortfolio a
JOIN cteDailyStats b
ON a.Year = b.Year
)
SELECT Issuer, [2015],[2016],[2017]
FROM pivotData 
PIVOT
(
SUM(c.Contrib)
FOR [Year] IN ([2015],[2016],[2017])
) AS PivotTable
GO
```

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe how simple that was. Why does those two columns create this issue with extra lines?

Comment: @MilesToGoBeforeISleep - In pivot source data should not have any extra columns else it will consider those also for pivoting thats why are seeing `NULL's`.. you can select `a.PNL` and `b.AvgNAV` columns in final `select` which is not needed in your case..